# state and city combobox with jquery UI plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to select state and cities according to the state (category and subcategory) but is giving a problem with the jquery ui plugin to search the value.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">



                $(function(){
                $('#cod_estados').change(function(){
                    if( $(this).val() ) {
                        $('#cod_cidades').hide();
                        $('.carregando').show();
                        $.getJSON('cidades.ajax.php?search=',{cod_estados: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                            var options = '<option value=""></option>'; 
                            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                                options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_cidades + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
                            }   
                            $('#cod_cidades').html(options).show();
                            $('.carregando').hide();
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#cod_cidades').html('<option value="">– Escolha um estado –</option>');
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
```

http://imageshack.us/g/10/99913872.jpg/

remembering that I am using other javascript code that will be is conflicting?

lap

'jQuery.noConflict () '

instead of $ and then comes the 
'(function () {'

but the code ceases to function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery in noConflict mode, you can remap `$` within your shortcut domReady call.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
    // Your code here, access $ as usual
});
```

Comment: Then I apologize, but I don't understand your problem.  Perhaps you could provide some additional clarity to your question.